# jQuery: Subtract value from another value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to *subtract numeric values* from a total value using jQuery.

However, when I subtract numbers I get a `-` before my final value!

so, lets say I have `300` as total and I take `4.99` from it, I get a number like this: `-296` instead of `296`.

I have created this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/57k08t7p/) so you can see the issue.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: Kindly first check your code well before asking others to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is incorrect. You need to update your equation to following

```
var finaltotal23 =  parseInt(inputval23) - parseInt(price23);

//inputVal23 is the value of input element i.e. 300
//price23 is the data attribute of button i.e. 4.99
```

Please find updated fiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/57k08t7p/1/